# Why are these two sums() not the same?

Tags: r, sum

I have two vectors:

```
parentvec<-c(1.4982, 18.18734, 901.14744)
childvec<-c(0.90268, 13.77532, 613.38298, 0.01845, 0.0681, 7.19925, 3.75315, 0.14333, 136.54008, 0.04766, 0.59077, 28.97255, 0.38608, 115.05258)
```

When I sum each of them, I get the same result:

```
> sum(childvec)
[1] 920.833

> sum(parentvec)
[1] 920.833
```

But when I subtract one from the other, I get a non-zero result:

```
> sum(childvec)-sum(parentvec)
[1] 1.136868e-13
```

What on earth is going on and how do I stop it?

In case this is relevant, I'm using Win10, with R 3.4.3.

Comment: `1.136868e-13` is basically zero. Do you actually need more precision than that?

Comment: Yes, because I'm using parentvec-childvec to get a TRUE or FALSE vector

Comment: You could add a step that checks if the difference is less than some threshold value like 1e-13, and make it zero if it is.